# ActionAttributeFilter vs. Delegatinghandler - advantages/disadvantages?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I want to log incoming json data from request and outgoing json in response.

After some search i noticed that both customized ActionAttributeFilter and DelegatingHandler can be used.
Are they any advantages/disadvantages ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Advantages / Disadvantages depends on your need.

Delegating handler is much higher in hierarchy of Web API request processing than ActionAttributeFilter. If you implement Delegating Handler, you are creating a Message handler, while if you create Action filter, your are creating filter that run just before the action method in the pipeline.

Although a message handler runs earlier in the pipeline, it can be advantageous in dealing 
requests at the earliest available opportunity. The message handler runs for all action methods, or at least all the action methods of a route. This should be considered when selecting the message handler to solve a problem. Action Filters can be applied to individual action methods, all methods in an Controller, or all methods across all controllers by
configuring the filter as a global filter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just need to log json data from request and response for all get/post methods in all controllers and nothing else. It sounds like action filters is the best solution in this case. Do i really need to configure something for it to be global or is it enough to annotate methods with that filter ?

Comment: FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters is used to register global filters. if you dont dot that, you will have to annotate each action and / or each function you would like this filter to run on.

Comment: I think for your particular case, it might make more sense to do a delegating handler (but it depends on what you want to log).   Note that the delegating handler runs before any authentication filters - so if you want to log requests that fail authentication/authorization too, you should make it a delegating handler.  If not, it should be an action filter (which occurs after the authentication/authorization).

Answer (score 3):

For your particular requirement, i.e. logging request and response, you should use a delegating handler.

The advantage of this is you can build a log object from the request AND the response at the same time. This is because the delegating handler runs around the request and response so will have access to both.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var log = new Log { Url = request.RequestUri };     
  var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
  log.ContentLength = response.ContentLength;
  this.LogAsync(log);
  return response;
}
```

With ActionFilter you can have methods that will execute before AND after the request but not throughout so you will need to think about correlating the logs somehow.